# Al pulsar botón se ejecute código PHP que devuelva 10 botones de descarga sin recargar la página en WP usando Ajax

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress

Sucede que tengo una web en WordPress en la que cada entrada tiene enlaces de descarga que son generados y obtenidos usando PHP desde un campo de Custom Field cada vez que se carga el post, entonces deseo que ese código PHP ya no se ejecute cada vez que se visualiza una entrada si no que se ejecute solo si el usuario hace click en un botón que lo llamaremos "Generar enlaces" el problema es que deseo que no se recargue la página al pulsar el botón (Usar Ajax), deseo que al pulsar el botón este desaparezca y se comience a ejecutar el código PHP que genera los enlaces y por supuesto aparezcan los botones de descarga generados segundos después de que PHP haya procesado todo el código. Es decir en un principio aparezca solo un único botón llamado "Generar enlaces" que al pulsarlo este desaparezca y se reemplace este fragmento de la página por los botones de descarga como en la siguiente imagen:

[image: Botones de descarga]
Necesariamente es necesario que solo se ejecute el fragmento de código PHP que genera los botones de descarga cuando se oprime el botón porque la razón es que PHP se toma en ejecutar ese código unos 50 segundos y cada vez que se carga una entrada esperar todo ese tiempo es un problema grave de experiencia para el usuario.

Tengo el siguiente código que es el que mejor se asemeja a la solución del problema, pero como mencioné ante, el problema es que necesito devolver y ejecutar código PHP no HTML como lo hace este.

Esto va en el single.php de las entrada (ó index.php de cada entrada) es el código que

```html
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function llamar(){
        $.ajax({
            url: '/wp-content/themes/NOMBREDEMITEMA/generador.php',
            type: 'post',
                success:  function (data) {
                        $("#resultado").html(data);
                }
        });
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<button type="button" name="name" class="clase" onClick="llamar();">Generar Enlaces</button>
Resultado: <span id="resultado"></span>
</body>
</html>
```

En vez de leer el HTML que devuelve la variable 'data' de Ajax necesito ejecutar código PHP (El cual lee el Custom Field del post que contiene URL's de descarga  y genera botones de descarga para cada uno) dentro del mismo single.php (No desde una fuente externa como lo está haciendo acá leyendo el resultado HTML de generador.php).

Les agradezco de antemano toda su ayuda !!

**NUEVO CÓDIGO IMPLEMENTADO**
single.php

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/wp-content/themes/NOMBREDEMITEMA/js/script.js"></script>

<button id="btnEnviar">Enviar</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

script.js

```js
$(function() {
    var $btnEnviar = $('#btnEnviar');
    var $divResult = $('#result');
    $btnEnviar.on('click', function() {
      $divResult.empty();
      var request =
        $.ajax({
          url: "/cont/themes/NOMBREDEMITEMA/generador.php",
          method: "GET",
          dataType: "html"
        });
  
      request.done(function(data) {
        var htmlButtons = '';
        $btnEnviar.hide()
        $("#result").html(data);
  
      });
  
      request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
        alert("Error en la petición: " + textStatus);
      });
  
    })
  });
```

generador.php

```html
<?php 
echo 'Hola Mundo';
?>
```

**CÓDIGO SOLUCIÓN @alo Malbarez (EN PROCESO)**

```
functions.php
```

```html
<?php
// imprimir el boton en el hook luego del content filter si hay customfield
function EMP_Boton_add_to_content( $content ) {
  $btnContent = "";
  if( is_single() ) {
    $postID = get_the_id();
    $ajax_url = admin_url('admin-ajax.php');
    $elCampoCustom = types_render_field("prueba-enlaces", array("output" => "raw"));
    if(!empty($elCampoCustom)) {

      // abro buffer asi el editor me colorea el html
      ob_start();?>
      <button class="button button-primary" id="mostrarEnlaces-<?php echo $postID;?>">Mostrar enlaces</button>
      <div id="resultados-<?php echo $postID;?>"></div>
      
      <script>
document.getElementById("mostrarEnlaces-<?php echo $postID;?>")
.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("resultados-<?php echo $postID;?>")
  .innerHTML = "<em>Procesando aguantame los trapos...</em>";
  const formData = new URLSearchParams();
  formData.append("action",  "post_get_enlacesCampoCustom");
  formData.append("post_id", <?php echo $postID;?>);
  fetch(
    "<?php echo $ajax_url;?>",
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      body: formData.toString(),
    }
  )
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(function(body) {
    document.getElementById("resultados-<?php echo $postID;?>").innerHTML = body;
  });
};
</script>

<?php
      // cierro buffer, lo guardo en una var
      $btnContent = ob_get_clean();
    }
  }
  // retorno el content + el html generado
  return $content . $btnContent;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'EMP_Boton_add_to_content' );

// action para usuarios anónimos: wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}
add_action(
  'wp_ajax_nopriv_nombreDeTuAction',
  'nombreDeTuFuncionParaElAction' );

// action para usuarios logueados: wp_ajax_{action}
add_action(
  'wp_ajax_nombreDeTuAction',
  'nombreDeTuFuncionParaElAction' );

  function post_get_enlacesCampoCustom(){
    $elCampoCustom = types_render_field("prueba-enlaces", array("output" => "raw"));
    // si tiene campo y si es ajax
    if(!empty($elCampoCustom) && defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {
      // abro buffer asi el editor me colorea el html
      ob_start();
      
      //COMIENZO DE MI CODIGO GENERADOR Y CLASIFICADOR DE ENLACES
      echo 'Hola Mundo by oijm17';

      //FIN DE MI CODIGO GENERADOR Y CLASIFICADOR DE ENLACES
      
      // cierro buffer, lo guardo en una var
      $responseContent = ob_get_clean();
      echo $responseContent;
    }
    die(); // sin esto se muestra un 0
  }

  function nombreDeTuFuncionParaElAction(){
    // Aquí procesamos el action
    if (!empty($_POST['unparametro'])) {
      echo "El parametro es:". $_POST['unparametro'];
    }
    // el procesador ajax por default devuelve un 0 al final, aquí evitamos eso
    die();
  }

?>
<script>
jQuery.post(
    "https://www.midominio.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", 
    {
        'action': 'nombreDeTuAction',
        'unparametro':   123
    }, 
    function(response) {
        console.log('La respuesta es: ', response)
    }
);
</script>
```

Comment: Bienvenido a Stackoverflow. La desesperación de dos días sin poder resolver un problema relativamente simple hace que no te expliques bien. De entrada te digo que si vas a usar Ajax, lo correcto es que todo lo que sea del lado del servidor (PHP) **se procese en un archivo aparte** el cual te devolverá lo que quieras para presentarlo en la página (y esto puede ser HTML o no, da igual).  **¿Estamos claros en eso?** Ahora, respira un poco, y explica bien las cosas. Y quita el horrible ¡Auxilio! en el título. Ya sabemos que estás desesperado y te vamos a ayudar, pero explícate mejor, con calma.

Comment: Creo que está clara mi explicación del problema. Gracias por la bienvenida !!

Comment: No, no está claro. Esto es totalmente confuso: *En vez de leer el HTML que devuelve la variable 'data' de Ajax necesito ejecutar código PHP (El cual lee el Custom Field del post que contiene URL's de descarga y genera botones de descarga para cada uno) dentro del mismo single.php (No desde una fuente externa como lo está haciendo acá leyendo el resultado HTML de generador.php).* Es como **si no entendieras del todo cómo funciona Ajax**. Escribí algunas cosas en **negritas** en mi anterior comentario y no has dicho si sí o si no. Si no tienes eso claro tu petición Ajax será un fracaso.

Comment: ... y la introducción a la pregunta también es confusa. Explica con toda simplicidad: 1. Lo que pretendes; 2. Cómo lo estás intentando hacer: 3. Qué es lo que no funciona.  Es muy simple, pero te has enrollado a dar explicaciones confusas que no permiten entender ninguno de esos tres puntos sin los cuales es imposible poder ayudarte.

Comment: Esta parte: `request.done(function(data) {`  es donde se trata la respuesta del servidor cuando ésta es exitosa. Pero ahora mismo no haces nada con la respuesta, que vendría en el parámetro `data` que está entre paréntesis. Si por ejemplo pones esto: `$divResult.append(data);` verás aparecer en el `div` la palabra `Hola mundo` que está devolviendo el servidor. Si observas el ejemplo basado en Github, se recorre el JSON, creando botones (dentro del `each`)  y luego esos botones se agregan al `div`. Quizá debí explicar mejor esa parte y no lo hice por rapidez.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress además de ser un CMS es también un framework, y como tal provee herramientas para tareas comunes. Todas las funciones las vamos a definir en el archivo `functions.php`

## El Ajax

En el caso de Ajax expone un procesador de peticiones al cual le envias el tipo de acción a realizar y los datos para dicha acción.

Este "procesador de requests" es `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` y además de procesar el request con la función correcta posee varios mecanismos para evitar XSS, CSFR y otras cosas que pasan en internet.

La forma de registrar una "action" para que pueda ser llamada por ajax es:

```
// action para usuarios anónimos: wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}
add_action(
  'wp_ajax_nopriv_nombreDeTuAction',
  'nombreDeTuFuncionParaElAction' );

// action para usuarios logueados: wp_ajax_{action}
add_action(
  'wp_ajax_nombreDeTuAction',
  'nombreDeTuFuncionParaElAction' );

function nombreDeTuFuncionParaElAction(){
  // Aquí procesamos el action
}
```

Aquí uso la misma `function` para ambos tipos de usuarios, adaptar a tus necesidades.

Una llamada ajax con jquery se vería así:

```
jQuery.post(
    "https://tudominio.com/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php", 
    {
        'action': 'nombreDeTuAction',
        'unparametro':   123
    }, 
    function(response) {
        console.log('La respuesta es: ', response);
    }
);
```

El parámetro `unparametro` lo vas a ver en la funcion como `$_POST['unparametro']`

```
function nombreDeTuFuncionParaElAction(){
  // Aquí procesamos el action
  if (!empty($_POST['unparametro'])) {
    echo "El parametro es:". $_POST['unparametro'];
  }
  // el procesador ajax por default devuelve un 0 al final, aquí evitamos eso
  die();
}
```

## El Botón

Para agregar cosas al contenido del post, dependiendo de si tiene o no un meta asociado, podemos usar el hook del filtro `the_content`, esto es un modificador(filter) del contenido del post que se aplica cuando uno llama a `<?php the_content();?>`, así que nos enganchamos ahí para no editar el `single.php` y agregamos un botón al final, junto con un div para los resultados:

```
// imprimir el boton en el hook luego del content filter si hay customfield
function EMP_Boton_add_to_content( $content ) {
  $btnContent = "";
  if( is_single() ) {
    $postID = get_the_id();
    $ajax_url = admin_url('admin-ajax.php');
    $elCampoCustom = get_post_meta($postID, 'elCampoCustom', TRUE);
    if(!empty($elCampoCustom)) {
      // abro buffer asi el editor me colorea el html
      ob_start();
      ?>
      <button
      class="button button-primary"
      id="mostrarEnlaces-<?php echo $postID;?>">Mostrar enlaces</button>
      <div id="resultados-<?php echo $postID;?>"></div>

      // cierro buffer, lo guardo en una var
      $btnContent = ob_get_clean();
    }
  }
  // retorno el content + el html generado
  return $content . $btnContent;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'EMP_Boton_add_to_content' );
```

## La llamada

Normalmente uno tendría un css y un js asociados y los encolaría con `wp_enqueue_script()` definiendo las dependencias (jQuery por ej) y el orden de carga.

En este caso, a fines de "brevidad" vamos a no depender de jQuery, usando vanilla javascript en un tag `<script>`, asi que lo del boton quedaría:

```
<button
class="button button-primary"
id="mostrarEnlaces-<?php echo $postID;?>">Mostrar enlaces</button>
<div id="resultados-<?php echo $postID;?>"></div>
<script>
document.getElementById("mostrarEnlaces-<?php echo $postID;?>")
.onclick = function() {
  document.getElementById("resultados-<?php echo $postID;?>")
  .innerHTML = "<em>Procesanding aguantame los trapos...</em>";
  const formData = new URLSearchParams();
  formData.append("action",  "post_get_enlacesCampoCustom");
  formData.append("post_id", <?php echo $postID;?>);
  fetch(
    "<?php echo $ajax_url;?>",
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      body: formData.toString(),
    }
  )
  .then(function(response) {
    return response.text();
  })
  .then(function(body) {
    document.getElementById("resultados-<?php echo $postID;?>").innerHTML = body;
  });
};
</script>
```

Aquí uso `fetch` con método `post` y paso los datos "form-urlencodeados" con la ayuda de `URLSearchParams()`, los ID de botón y respuesta los defino con el id del post así no hay que hacer mucha movida con clases css (esto permite mostrar mas de un post con su propio boton), adapte a su necesidad y realidad.

## Todo junto

En este ejemplo el `custom_field` se llama `"elCampoCustom"` (ya pensaré un nombre mas fácil de recordar), y la función ajax lo que hace es generar enlaces a buscadores con las palabras de este campo. Además hay por ahi un `sleep(5)` para simular un retraso en la respuesta.

Todo el código junto quedaría algo así:

`functions.php`

```
<?php
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'enqueue_parent_styles' );

function enqueue_parent_styles() {
  wp_enqueue_style( 'parent-style', get_template_directory_uri().'/style.css' );
}

// imprimir el boton en el hook luego del content filter si hay customfield
function EMP_Boton_add_to_content( $content ) {
  $btnContent = "";
  if( is_single() ) {
    $postID = get_the_id();
    $ajax_url = admin_url('admin-ajax.php');
    $elCampoCustom = get_post_meta($postID, 'elCampoCustom', TRUE);
    if(!empty($elCampoCustom)){
      // abro buffer asi el editor me colorea el html
      ob_start();
      ?>
      <button
      class="button button-primary"
      id="mostrarEnlaces-<?php echo $postID;?>">Mostrar enlaces</button>
      <div id="resultados-<?php echo $postID;?>"></div>
      <script>
      document.getElementById("mostrarEnlaces-<?php echo $postID;?>")
      .onclick = function() {
        document.getElementById("resultados-<?php echo $postID;?>")
        .innerHTML = "<em>Procesanding aguantame los trapos...</em>";
        const formData = new URLSearchParams();
        formData.append("action",  "post_get_enlacesCampoCustom");
        formData.append("post_id", <?php echo $postID;?>);
        fetch(
          "<?php echo $ajax_url;?>",
          {
            method: "POST",
            headers: {
              "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
            },
            body: formData.toString(),
          }
        )
        .then(function(response) {
          return response.text();
        })
        .then(function(body) {
          document.getElementById("resultados-<?php echo $postID;?>").innerHTML = body;
        });
      };
      </script>
      <?php
      // cierro buffer, lo guardo en una var
      $btnContent = ob_get_clean();
    }
  }
  // retorno el content + el html generado
  return $content . $btnContent;
}
add_filter( 'the_content', 'EMP_Boton_add_to_content' );

// para creacion de links
define(
'SEARCH_LINKS', [
'SOes' => [
'text'=> 'StackOverflow Español',
'url' => 'https://es.stackoverflow.com/search?q=',
],
'SOen' => [
'text'=>'StackOverflow',
'url' => 'https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=',
],
'google' => [
'text'=>'Google',
'url' => 'https://www.google.com/search?q=',
],
'googleIMG' => [
'text'=>'Google Imágenes',
'url' => 'https://www.google.com/search?tbm=isch&q=',
],
]
);

// actions ajax post
// el action _nopriv es para definir otro comportamiento si el usuario
// no tiene privilegios (x ej: no está logueado)
add_action(
  'wp_ajax_nopriv_post_get_enlacesCampoCustom',
  'post_get_enlacesCampoCustom'
);
add_action(
  'wp_ajax_post_get_enlacesCampoCustom',
  'post_get_enlacesCampoCustom'
);
function post_get_enlacesCampoCustom(){
  $elCampoCustom = get_post_meta( $_POST['post_id'], 'elCampoCustom', TRUE);
  // si tiene campo y si es ajax
  if(!empty($elCampoCustom) && defined( 'DOING_AJAX' ) && DOING_AJAX ) {
    // simulo 5 segundos de proceso
    sleep(5);
    // abro buffer asi el editor me colorea el html
    ob_start(); ?>
    <ul>
      <?php foreach(SEARCH_LINKS as $eID=>$enlace) : ?>
      <li><a
           href="<?php echo $enlace['url'].urlencode($elCampoCustom)?>"
           target="tab-<?php echo $eID;?>"><?php echo $enlace['text']?></a></li>
      <?php  endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
    <?php
    // cierro buffer, lo guardo en una var
    $responseContent = ob_get_clean();
    echo $responseContent;
  }
  die(); // sin esto se muestra un 0
}
```

Comment: Bro estuve tratando de implementar tu código en mi proyecto pero no he sido capaz, no sé mucho de AJAX, quiero en vez de buscar enlaces uniendo palabras + las URLs de búsqueda, los extraiga directamente desde mi custom field con este código que uso en PHP:

types_render_field("prueba-enlaces", array("output" => "raw"));en este caso los guardaría en $elCampoCustom

Tampoco sé cómo hacer para que NO SIMULE el retraso de 5 segundos.Ademas deseo que solo si presiona el botón Mostrar enlaces se ejecute un fragmento de código PHP que clasifica, y ejecuta el ShortCode que genera botones de descar

Comment: el retraso se simula con el `sleep(5);` borras esa línea o le agregas un `// ` adelante para comentarla. justo antes del `ob_start()` creas un array con los datos procesados, luego dentro del foreach haces los shortcodes con el array, esa separación entre proceso e impresión te permite luego cachear el asunto y no tener que procesar nuevamente las cosas

Comment: Bro, a cual ob_start(); te refieres ? hay 2 en el código, estoy usando y modificando el código functions.php tuyo en el que está todo junto. Lo he incluido al final de la pregunta para que veas los cambios que he hecho y para que por favor puedas orientarme más fácil.

Comment: Fijate de ir implementando cada parte si la necesitás o no: si ya usas jQuery y tenes el boton "mostrar enlaces" probá armar la parte del ajax, sin hacer caso al action de insertarlo en el filtro de content. Hay 2 `ob_start()` pues uno está en el insertar botón y otro en el armar el resultado del ajax. Concentrate en la primer parte "El Ajax" y una vez que tenes un ajax funcional que diga "Hola Mundo" encarale al resto.

Comment: Implementando el código que he incluido y actualizado al final de la pregunta de nuevo, veo que aparecen ahora 2 botones "mostrar enlaces" uno al final y otro como antes de la mitad del post. El primero si funciona (pero devuelve un 0 (cero)) y el otro no hace nada. Me puede orientar cómo hago para que funcione y solucionar lo de los botones ? Por otro lado no entiendo dónde colocar mi código PHP para que diga al menos un "Hola Mundo", señalé con comentarios las lineas que pienso debe ir este código pero igual estoy reconfundido, por favor ayúdame que debo borrar o reemplazar en el código ?

Answer (score 0):

Este ejemplo hace algo parecido a lo que quieres, espero que te pueda servir como ayuda.

Hace lo siguiente:

- Lanza una petición Ajax a la API de Github (es una URL externa, pero si fuera interna funcionaría igual)
- La API responde con un JSON con información sobre usuarios de Github. Ese JSON es recuperado en la función `done`, es leído y se toman datos de él para crear un botón por usuario...
- Finalmente esos datos son presentados en el contenedor cuyo id es `result`.
- El botón `Enviar` es ocultado con `hide`.

Si por ejemplo, tu archivo PHP devolviese los botones ya creados, deberás cambiar el `dataType` de la petición Ajax por `html`. Aunque lo más recomendable es devolver un JSON y parsearlo en el cliente. El JSON es mucho más ligero de transportar. Descargas de trabajo suplementario al servidor, haciendo que la respuesta sea construida en el cliente.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

```js
$(function() {
  var $btnEnviar = $('#btnEnviar');
  var $divResult = $('#result');
  $btnEnviar.on('click', function() {
    $divResult.empty();
    var request =
      $.ajax({
        url: "https://api.github.com/users",
        method: "GET",
        dataType: "json"
      });

    request.done(function(data) {
      var htmlButtons = '';

      $.each(data, function(k, v) {
        htmlButtons += `<button id="${v.id}">${v.login}`;
      });
      $btnEnviar.hide()
      $divResult.append(htmlButtons);

    });

    request.fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
      alert("Error en la petición: " + textStatus);
    });

  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
Por favor, presiona el botón para probar el código: 
<button id="btnEnviar">Enviar</button>

<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: Está bien. Pero ten en cuenta lo que digo sobre el JSON y el `dataType`. Si, para probar, cambias el `dataType` a `html` y en el `done` quitas todo lo del `each` mostrando solamente `data` en el contenedor, debería funcionar. Ya para otras cosas más complejas es mejor devolver desde el servidor un array con JSON usando `json_encode` y trabajar la respuesta en el `done` haciendo algo parecido al ejemplo de Github. Es decir, no todos los tratamientos de respuesta en el `done` tienen por qué ser iguales, dependen del tipo de respuesta que devuelve el servidor y de su estructura.

Comment: @oijm17 lee mi último comentario en la pregunta.

Comment: @oijm17 ten en cuenta que este sitio **funciona por preguntas**. Conocer la diferencia entre `append` y `html` es algo muy interesante, responder a ello en un comentario sería un desperdicio. Recomiendo primero que busques en el sitio si no hay alguna pregunta que conteste a tu duda y si no la encuentres que abras una nueva pregunta. De hecho, podría ser una pregunta muy interesante que generará respuestas interesantes. Pero primero busca, no sea que ya exista y crees algo duplicado. Me alegro de que haya funcionado. Ajax es una de las mejores cosas que se han inventado, ya lo verás.

Comment: Correcto ahora tengo problemas para leer el contenido de una variable declarada en el single.php que guarda las URL's de descarga en el custom Field de la entrada de WP y así poder generar los botones de descarga desde el archivo generador.php para luego devolverlos en el parámetro llamado 'data', me podrías echar una mano con esto o genero un nuevo tema de discusión ?

Comment: @oijm17 es mejor que crees otra pregunta, dando esto por zanjado. Debe ser sin duda algún otro problema. Una nueva pregunta ayudará a abrir nuevos horizontes y a tener otros puntos de vista (de otros usuarios). De todos modos, algo importante en Ajax es entender que, tanto lo que se envía como lo que se recibe en la comunicación cliente/servidor puede tener varios tipos o formatos y en base a eso debe ser tanto la recuperación de esos datos en el servidor como la elaboración de la respuesta que el mismo emite y la forma en que el cliente debe tratar esa respuesta. Son pequeñas variaciones...

Comment: Hay alguna forma de que Ajax ejecute o más bien llame al código PHP sin hacer el llamado a un archivo PHP externo (generador.php) ? Es que sí lo logro hacer desde el mismo single.php donde está el código Ajax me convendría.

Comment: @oijm17 te equivocas al pensar que es más conveniente hacer todo desde el mismo archivo. Para hacer eso tendrías que: 1. Agregar a la URL los datos que quieres mandar al servidor; 2. Recargar el archivo con esos datos agregados a la URL (algo pésimo desde el punto de vista de experiencia de usuario y desde el punto de vista estético); 3. Manejar la respuesta del servidor; 4. Olvidarte de Ajax, el cual no existe para eso, sino para todo lo contrario. Ajax existe para poder enviar/recibir datos entre cliente/servidor de forma transparente, sin tener que andar recargando páginas.