# Como leo una variable declarada en single.php de WordPress desde archivo PHP externo?

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theme

Tengo problemas para leer el contenido de una variable declarada en **single.php** (index.php de cada entrada) del tema activo en WordPress, esa variable la estoy invocando desde un archivo PHP externo llamado **generador.php** que cree dentro de el mismo directorio del tema activo; esta variable PHP llamada **$enlaces** guarda las URL's de descarga obtenidas desde el custom Field de cada entrada de WordPress. El archivo **generador.php** se encarga de  generar botones de descarga y realizar algunas modificaciones a las URL's (que no creo que sea relevante para este caso, por lo tanto no voy a mencionar).

Gracias de antemano por toda su colaboración !!

**Código Usado Basándome en Ejemplo de @brasofilo**

single.php

```html
<?php $enlaces = 'Soy Una Variable';?>
```

generador.php

```html
<?php 
define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );
require( $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] .'/wp-load.php' ); // ajustar sí necesário
echo $enlaces;
?>
```

Comment: Te recomiendo colocar aquí las partes relevantes de tu código para poderte ayudar.

Comment: Quizá el problema de fondo no sea ese... sí tienes ese archivo dentro de la carpeta del tema, ¿significa que estás usando `generador.php` dentro de WordPress?

Comment: si exacto, este archivo lo incluí en el mismo directorio de mi tema activo de WordPress (y en el mismo de single.php) en este caso seria: "/wp-content/themes/NOMBREDEMITEMA/generador.php" y ""/wp-content/themes/NOMBREDEMITEMA/single.php"

Comment: @RockoDev he actualizado el tema y he escrito el código básico de lo que tengo basándome en el ejemplo de @ brasofilo pero sigue sin funcionar.

Comment: En vez de mostrar cómo estás usando mi código, sería mejor enseñar tu proprio código y explicar su lógica. Luego, no tiene ningun sentido que el valor de `$enlaces` sea una simples frase...

Comment: @brasofilo Brother, es que el código mío es casi lo mismo que el tuyo porque como es muy básico no tiene ninguna ciencia. Si incluyera mi propio código seria solo borrar las 2 primeras primeras lineas de código del archivo generador.php y ya está.

Comment: Bueno, es como ir al mecánico sin llevar el coche :/

Answer (score 0):

Podes incluir el `generador.php` luego de declarar la variable, por ejemplo:

`single.php`

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying all single posts
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Seventeen
 * @since 1.0
 * @version 1.0
 */

get_header(); 

$mivariable = "hola";
include_once(__DIR__.'/generador.php');
?>
```

`generador.php`

```
<pre>
  <?php var_dump($mivariable);?>
</pre>
```

Eso te incluye el generador e imprime el valor en un bloque pre formateado justo debajo del header.

Si la onda es generar nuevo contenido en base al post actual y mostrarlo al hacer click en un botón ni siquiera es necesario un include o un archivo aparte, hay varias formas de hacerlo, transcribo la mas "slum programming way" ®:

`single.php`

```
<?php
/**
* The template for displaying all single posts
*
* @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/#single-post
*
* @package WordPress
* @subpackage Twenty_Seventeen
* @since 1.0
* @version 1.0
*/

get_header(); ?>

<div class="wrap">
  <div id="primary" class="content-area">
    <main id="main" class="site-main" role="main">

      <?php
      /* Start the Loop */
      while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();

      get_template_part( 'template-parts/post/content', get_post_format() );

      // If comments are open or we have at least one comment, 
      // load up the comment template.
      if ( comments_open() || get_comments_number() ) :
        comments_template();
      endif;


      /*** AQUI PARSEAMOS EL CONTENIDO DEL POST ***/
      $contenido = get_the_content();

      // extraer links https://stackoverflow.com/a/24798689/1423096

      $re = '/<a href=\\"([^\\"]*)\\">(.*)<\\/a>/iU';

      if($num_found = preg_match_all($re, $contenido, $matches)) :
        $losLinks = $matches[0];

        /*** AQUI IMPRIMIMOS UN BOTON Y EL DIV OCULTO ***/
        ?>
        <div>
          <button
          class="button button-primary"
          onclick="document.getElementById('loslinks').style.display = 'block';"
          >Mostrar enlaces</button>
          <div id="loslinks" style="display:none;">
            <ul>
              <?php foreach($losLinks as $link) :?>
                <li><?php echo $link;?></li>
              <?php endforeach;?>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php
      endif;
      /*******************************************/


      the_post_navigation( array(
        'prev_text' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' .
        __( 'Previous Post', 'twentyseventeen' ) . 
        '</span><span aria-hidden="true" class="nav-subtitle">' . 
        __( 'Previous', 'twentyseventeen' ) . 
        '</span> <span class="nav-title"><span class="nav-title-icon-wrapper">' .
        twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'arrow-left' ) ) .
        '</span>%title</span>',
        'next_text' => '<span class="screen-reader-text">' .
        __( 'Next Post', 'twentyseventeen' ) . 
        '</span><span aria-hidden="true" class="nav-subtitle">' . 
        __( 'Next', 'twentyseventeen' ) . 
        '</span> <span class="nav-title">%title<span class="nav-title-icon-wrapper">' . 
        twentyseventeen_get_svg( array( 'icon' => 'arrow-right' ) ) .
        '</span></span>',
      ) );

    endwhile; // End of the loop.
    ?>

  </main><!-- #main -->
</div><!-- #primary -->
<?php get_sidebar(); ?>
</div><!-- .wrap -->

<?php get_footer();
```

Lo ideal sería un hook o un shortcode en el functions.php, o incluso mas portable armar un plugin.

Comment: Gracias, pero lo que pasa es que yo necesito es lo contrario es decir: desde el archivo generador.php ==> llamar a la variable $enlaces declarada en el archivo single.php y básicamente simplemente hacer un echo para comprobar que funcione, luego si haría algo mas complejo.

Comment: @oijm17, ya van dos respuestas que no aciertan entender tu problema... porfa, explica la cosa en detalle en tu pregunta.

Comment: @brasofilo cuando se llame al archivo generador.php (El cual invocaré usando Ajax cuando desde el FrontEnd se pulse un botón que aparecerá en cada entrada de WP)==>Necesito obtener el valor de una variable String $enlaces declarada en el single.php que contiene enlaces de descarga==>Estos enlaces  de $enlaces se procesarán y finalmente se generarán botones en el generador.php (Este código ya lo tengo)==>Después de generados los botones de descarga, a través de Ajax devolveré los botones generados, en el FrontEnd de single.php (Página de entrada WP) sin que se recargue la página (Ya tengo esto)

Comment: @ojim17 pon esa explicación en la pregunta, haciendo click en [editar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/203428/edit) , ajax en wordpress funciona de una manera diferente a como lo estas planteando (cuestiones de seguridad y framework)

Comment: @oijm17, seguro que es un ["Problema XY"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) Estás fijado en una cosa, cuando lo que hay que arreglar es otra.

Comment: @brasofilo Jajaja no, no brother, lo que está en la pregunta en particular es lo que quiero conseguir en concreto, expliqué lo otro porque dijiste que me expusiera mejor.

Comment: @brasofilo si la intención es mediante ajax generar información relativa al post actual presionando un botón, la mecánica es diferente. De la forma que la planteas no necesitas ajax: que generador.php (con include) en vez de hacer un vardump imprima un div oculto y el boton lo muestra.

Comment: @oijm17 debía editar su pregunta para aclarar las cosas...

Comment: je le pifie al tag, el comment es para OP

Comment: @aloMalbarez vi tu ultimo comentario y me sembraste la inquietud de qué forma se podría implementar esto sin usar Ajax ? y sin recargar la página al presionar el botón para generar los enlaces ?

Comment: ahi te puse un ejemplo basado en el single.php del theme Twenty_Seventeen, busca y extrae enlaces, si hay muestra un botón (entre el post y el paginador) y al hacer click muestra el div de los enlaces.

Comment: @aloMalbarez excelente funciona bastante bien (lo tendré en cuenta, para futuros proyectos) pero realmente mi objetivo es que basándonos en tu ejemplo no se ejecute el foreach (o cualquier Código PHP que incluya allí) hasta que el usuario no presione el botón "Mostrar Enlaces", porque resulta que dicho código PHP tarda hasta 50 segundos en ejecutarse y entonces el problema seria que hasta que no se ejecute este PHP la entrada de WP no va a mostrarse. Se puede lograr que no se ejecute solo hasta presionar el botón y sin usar archivos externos (Así como en tu ejemplo) ?

Comment: eso lo respondí en la otra pregunta https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/204439/81450, podes hacer el include en el callback del ajax `post_get_enlacesCampoCustom()`

Answer (score 0):

La primero, si quieres mostrar algo de un archivo php en otro directamente tienes que importar ese archivo en el otro como te comenta alo Malbarez, claro que en tu caso sería:

```
include_once(__DIR__.'/single.php');
```

El tema es que por lo que veo no quieres eso, ya que sería pasar los que estás haciendo en el archivo single.php al archivo generador.php, lo que tu quieres es tener acceso a esa variable de alguna manera, en cuyo caso se me ocurre que crees una variable de sesión para esa variable $enlaces en single.php y que luego en el archivo generador.php obtengas esa variable.

single.php

```
<?php 
  session_start();
  $_SESSION['enlaces'] = 'Soy Una Variable';
?>
```

generador.php

```
<?php 
  session_start();

  if(isset($_SESSION['enlaces']))
    print_r($_SESSION['enlaces']);
?>
```

Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias @zerocool, realicé la prueba y por ahora funciona con una variable string, voy a implementarlo con todos los juguetes a ver qué tal, pero en teoría debería funcionar. Lo que me inquieta es si se puede hacer esto de otra forma que no sea usando variables de sesión ?

Comment: @zercool puse tu código a prueba con mi código de generador.php que genera los botones y modifica los enlaces y me topé con un error 500 en el archivo generador.php entonces me di cuenta que el problema era ocasionado por la función de WordPress do_shortcode('NOMBREFUNCIÓN') que genera los botones de descarga, el caso es que esta función no es válida para el archivo generador.php y por esto el error.En fin sabes cómo hacer para que el archivo generador.php también me interprete esa función ? y de paso si se te ocurre otra forma de transferir los valores de las variables SIN VARIABLES DE SESION

Comment: El tema del error con la funcion do_shortcode debe ser otro post en concreto para que preguntes directamente y la gente encuentre fácil el tema, así otra persona que lo tenga claro te puede responder ya que en los comentarios se pierde tu nueva situación.Del otro punto no se me ocurre otra cosa que no sea guardar en la base de datos y que en generador.php leas esa info de la bd pero eso es mucho para poco... Indica el error que te dió a ver y de nuevo eso sería mejor que lo hagas en otro post. Saludos!