# Como ejecuto la función do_shortcode() desde un archivo externo a Wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Tengo un archivo externo al tema que uso en Wordpress llamado generador.php que genera y guarda en un array PHP asociativo (clasifica por nombre de Hosting) enlaces de descarga, cada vez que es llamado desde el frontEnd (Single.php) pero necesito que este mismo archivo (generador.php), me permita ejecutar la función do_shortcode(), ya que al ser un archivo tercero a WordPress desde allí no reconoce el llamado a esta función que necesito para ejecutar el shortcode:

Es decir necesito que yo pueda ejecutar esta función en concreto:

```html
do_shortcode('[maxbutton id="3" url="'https://url.com'" window="new" nofollow="true"]')
```

Gracias por toda su colaboración de antemano !!

Comment: Tendrás que "extraer" la función que necesitas (con todo lo que use internamente para funcionar) a un fichero externo y cargarlo en tu fichero "generador.php". Saludos.

Comment: Para usar funciones como si estuvieses en el entorno de WP, basta con incluir el archivo `'wp-load.php`.  Por ejemplo: `require ('wp-load.php');  //poner la ruta correcta donde se encuentra el archivo`. Si estás usando tu propio tema, que no es uno de WP, debes poner también esta línea antes de todo: `define( 'WP_USE_THEMES', false );`

Comment: @A.Cedano correcto, gracias ahora funciona pero no como lo esperada, porque si ejecuta el shortcode, pero no muestra los estilos de los botones, solo muestra (Enlaces + estructura HTML de cada Link), pero la función que ejecuta el ShortCode ( do_shortcode('[maxbutton id="3" url="'https://url.com'" window="new" nofollow="true"]') ) ejecutándola desde single.php si genera HTML+CSS y muestra los botones correctamente, como en la imagen de este tema en el que colaboraste "https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/203069/al-pulsar-botón-se-ejecute-código-php-que-devuelva-10-botones-de-descarga-sin-re"

Comment: por qué en `generador.php` y no en `single.php`? desde dónde se llamaría a `generador.php` (la url)? donde se imprimiría el shortcode (en un single post dentro de wordpress, en otro lado fuera de wordpress)?

Comment: @aloMalbarez desde single.php y al pulsar el botón "Generar Enlaces" (Solo al hacer esto) se llama a ==>generador.php este ejecuta la función do_shortcode('[maxbutton id="3" url="'https://url.com'" window="new"]') y arrojaría este caso uno solo botón con la URL "https://url.com'" ) ==> Luego a través de Ajax y desde single.php recuperaría el botón(es) generados en generador.php y los expondría en el frontend de cada entrada (single.php) sin recargar la página. El ShortCode se ejecuta en generador.php porque se requiere que no se ejecute su código hasta que pulse el botón "Generar Enlaces".