# Mostrar resultado de consulta SQL en html

Tags: php, mysql, sql, wordpress, php7

He creado un plugin de WordPress donde recojo los datos de un formulario y los uso para hacer una consulta sql. En el formulario los usuarios tienen una clave de tarjeta, y un numero de tarjeta, al introducir los dos campos ha de dar un valor que son los puntos acumulados de la tarjeta.
El problema que tengo es que al calcularse el plugin me muestra el dato en la parte superior izquierda de mi pantalla, y quiero que lo muestre en una parte especifica (un custom html), quiero que se muestre debajo del formulario del cual recoge los datos.
Codigo del plugin:

```
 <?php
 $NumTarjetaFidelizacion = $_POST['NumTarjetaFidelizacion'];
$ClaveTarjeta = $_POST['ClaveTarjeta'];
global $wpdb;
$puntos = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT puntos FROM nikkiclub WHERE numerotarjeta='$NumTarjetaFidelizacion' AND Clavetarjeta='$ClaveTarjeta'" );
echo($puntos);
```

este es el codigo que use para el plugin que me cree, el cual me muestra los datos correctamente pero no consigo que los muestre en la parte que necesito, he probado a meterlo en un function pero no se me ejecuta al darle al boton del formulario no se por que cuando el boton ha tenido el onclick y demas bien puesto pero no se ejecuta el codigo

```
function comprobarPuntos(){
$NumTarjetaFidelizacion = $_POST['NumTarjetaFidelizacion'];
$ClaveTarjeta = $_POST['ClaveTarjeta'];
global $wpdb;
$puntos = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT puntos FROM nikkiclub WHERE 
numerotarjeta='$NumTarjetaFidelizacion' AND Clavetarjeta='$ClaveTarjeta'" );
echo($puntos);
```

El codigo html(Esta en un custom html en WordPress):

```html
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="NumTarjetaFidelizacion" required="">
<input type="text" name="ClaveTarjeta" required="">
<input type="submit" value="Consultar" >
<p>Tu saldo es: </p>
<?php comprobarPuntos(); ?>
</form>
```

Otro codigo html que he probado:

```html
<form method="post">
<input type="text" name="NumTarjetaFidelizacion" required="">
<input type="text" name="ClaveTarjeta" required="">
<input type="submit" value="Consultar" onclick="comprobarPuntos();" >
<p>Tu saldo es: </p>
</form>
```

Conseguí por medio de un include mostrar los datos de php en un html distinto y por medio de JavaScript mostrarlos en un alert, pero necesito mostrarlo en un apartado de la pagina que es un custom html no en un archivo html generado por mi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El "onclick" del HTML espera un evento JavaScript. No puedes llamar a una función de PHP allí.

Para tu primer ejemplo, cambia la función comprobarPuntos() para que retorne los puntos, en lugar de escribirlos directamente. Y luego escribes

```
<p>Tu saldo es: </p>
<?= comprobarPuntos(); ?>
```

Para el segundo ejemplo, puedes intentarlo por ajax, haciendo una función JavaScript que consume el backend y escribe la respuesta en una div, por ejemplo.

Comment: Creo que te refieres con que retorne los puntos a esto no?
 function comprobarPuntos(){
    $NumTarjetaFidelizacion = $_POST['NumTarjetaFidelizacion'];
 $ClaveTarjeta = $_POST['ClaveTarjeta'];
 global $wpdb;
 $puntos = $wpdb->get_var( "SELECT puntos FROM nikkiclub WHERE numerotarjeta='$NumTarjetaFidelizacion' AND Clavetarjeta='$ClaveTarjeta'" );
 echo ($puntos);
 return $puntos;
}

Comment: con respecto a Ajax no se practicamente nada, he echo ahora un include por el cual me lo manda a un fichero html, donde por medio de javaScript me almacena el dato y puedo mostrarlo por un alert pero claro no se como puedo hacer que eso me lo muestre en el apartado que quiero de la pagina. Gracias

Comment: Hay que tener en cuenta que HTML es lenguaje frontend, así que no puedes escribir tags PHP dentro del HTML (por eso he comentado lo de ajax). Ahora que pusiste el return, <?= comprobarPuntos(); ?> (o <?php echo comprobarPuntos(); ?> enseña el dato donde quieres? Si es así, quita el  "echo ($puntos);" de tú función para que no lo escriba también en la parte superior de la página. Sobre el JavaScript, si consigues hacer un alert(mensaje), a lo mejor también te sirve cambiarlo por un document.getElementById('ejemplo').innerHTML = mensaje y luego <p>Tu saldo es: </p><div id="ejemplo"></div>

Comment: No lo consegui con php con ninguna de las dos opciones que me pasaste voy a probar por javaScript si no me tocara verme algun curso rapido de Ajax. gracias

Comment: No me lo permite, supongo que es por que no puedo hacer un include a la pagina en la que lo necesito mostrar, ya que no me se la ruta y no me vale con el enlace ya que no es un archivo en si, y al custom html de la pagina lo mismo no puedo enlazarlo con un include hay que yo sepa.

Comment: para ajax en wordpress hay un poco de código aquí https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/204439/81450 fijate si se entiende la explicación del mecanismo

Comment: No me entero bien con este codigo la verdad no se como hacerlo, alguien me echa una mano?