# ¿Por qué ajax en WP devuelve toda la página?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, wordpress

Estoy realizando una petición ajax en wordpress de lo mas común, la cual debe devolver un simple string php, en vez de eso me devuelve todo el html de la pag. principal, soy nuevo en wp y ya lo odio, ya probé especificar el dataType: 'text' y sigue devolviendo lo mismo, ¿Que debo hacer para que me devuelva el dato correcto?.

**Script PHP**

```
//AÑADE ARCHIVO JS/AJAX
function subs_ajax_add(){
  wp_enqueue_script(
    'subs_ajax',
    get_theme_file_uri( 'js/subs_ajax.js' ),
    array('jquery')
  );    
}

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts','subs_ajax_add');

//AÑADE LA FUNCIÓN PHP QUE PROCESA LA PETICIÓN
function subsAjax(){
  echo "Funciona";
  exit();
}

add_action('wp_ajax_subsAjax','subsAjax');
```

**Script JS**

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {

  $('#year_capt').on('change', function() {
    jQuery.ajax({ 
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'text',
      url: '/wordpress/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php',
      data: { action: 'subsAjax' },
      success: function(result){
        console.log(result);
      },
      error: function(error) {
        console.log(error);
      }
    });
  }); 
});
```

Comment: Si la petición es GET, como en este caso, lo que veas en el navegador va a ser igual a lo que recibirías por el ajax. Es claro que: o la URL está mal o le falta algo, puedes probarlo pegando esa dirección en el navegador y ver que aparece.

Comment: E probado con post y la url la he especificado con un location pero aun así, me sigue mandando lo mismo

Answer (score 0):

Al parecer el script no está encontrando el procesador de ajax ( `wp-admin/admin-ajax.php` )

Wordpress tiene varias opciones para implementar ajax, y si estás empezando puede ser un poco mucho de procesar por lo disperso de la documentación.

Aquí te dejo una plantilla en base a tu código de cómo armar un ajax y enqueuar un script con parámetros ( para que el script sepa donde llamar ), lleva comentarios de para qué es cada cosa:

en `functions.php`

```
// por si son varios los scripts: guardamos la url del child-theme
define( 'CHILD_THEME_URL', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() );

// por si lo usamos en muchos lados: guardamos el url del procesador ajax
define( 'AJAX_URL', admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) );

function soEs291356_cargar_scripts(){
  // registramos el script con un nombre
  wp_register_script(
    'subs_ajax', // nombre
    CHILD_THEME_URL . '/js/subs_ajax.js', // source
    [ 'jquery' ], // dependencias ( array de nombres de otros scripts registrados )
    false, // versión del script
    true // cargar en footer
  );

  // le definimos parámetros al script
  wp_localize_script(
    'subs_ajax', // nombre del script
    'SUBS_AJAX_PARAMS', // nombre del objeto javascript con nuestros parámetros
    [ // array de parametros key = value
      'ajax_url' => AJAX_URL, // a donde hacer la petición
      'seguridad' => wp_create_nonce( // creamos un token nonce para el action
        'subs_ajax_' // nombre del contexto ( action_ )
      ),
    ]
  );

  // finalmente enqueuamos el script ya parametrizado
  wp_enqueue_script( 'subs_ajax' ); // nombre del script
}

// agregamos la función al action donde se cargan los scripts del frontend
add_action(
  'wp_enqueue_scripts', // el action
  'soEs291356_cargar_scripts' // el nombre de la función
);

/*** AJAX actions ***/
// ajax action para usuarios logueados
add_action(
  'wp_ajax_subsAjax', // wp_ajax_{action}
  'subsAjax' // función que procesa el action
);
// ajax action para usuarios anónimos o no logueados
add_action(
  'wp_ajax_nopriv_subsAjax', // wp_ajax_nopriv_{action}
  'subsAjax' // función que procesa el action
);

function subsAjax(){
  // Procesamos el action
  $nonceValid = check_ajax_referer( // verificamos el referer
  'subs_ajax_', // nombre del contexto
  'seguridad' , // nombre del token
  true // rechazar la conexión si el token no es válido o expiró
  );

  echo "Hola!" . PHP_EOL; // enviar texto
  if ( !empty( $_POST[ 'valor' ] ) ){ // si enviaron algo
    echo "Que significa {$_POST[ 'valor' ]} ?" . PHP_EOL; // se lo devolvemos
  }
  die(0); // para que cierre la conexión ( sino WP agrega un exit code 1 )
}
```

La petición en javascript la puse en una función separada así la podes testear por consola:

`js/subs_ajax.js`

```
jQuery( document ).ready( function() {
  console.log( SUBS_AJAX_PARAMS ); // verificamos que recibimos parametros
  jQuery( '#year_capt' ).on( 'change', function() {
    // enviamos el valor
    soEs291356_mandar_ajax( jQuery( this ).val() );
  });

});

function soEs291356_mandar_ajax( $valor ){
  // creamos un formdata urlencodeado para enviar por POST
  const formData = new URLSearchParams();
  formData.append( "action",  "subsAjax" );
  formData.append( "seguridad", SUBS_AJAX_PARAMS.seguridad ); // el token
  formData.append( "valor", $valor ); // datos a enviar

  fetch( SUBS_AJAX_PARAMS.ajax_url, // el script sabe donde pedir
    {
      method: "POST",
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      },
      body: formData.toString(),
    }
  ).then( function( response ) { // procesamos la respuesta
    if ( 200 != response.status ) { // 200 = ok
      return "Hubo un error";
    }
    return response.text();
  }).then( function( body ) { // procesamos el body
    console.log( body ); // mostramos el cuerpo de la respuesta
  });

}
```

Otro ejemplo de cómo hacer ajax y devolver texto ( con una explicación un poco mas extensa ) lo podés ver en una respuesta parecida: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/204439/81450